# Django ORM query question: How to filter by a list?

Tags: django, django-models

```
name = ['a','b']      # Hard coded list
customers = Customer.objects.filter(name=[]) # Want to filter by that list.
```

How to write such a query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Customer.objects.filter(name__in=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in